# How can I get gulp-sass to compile bootstrap CSS definitions rather than just output the import statement?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, gulp

I'm trying to pull in the Sass bootstrap source (.SCSS), make some customisations (via another .SCSS) and spit out a CSS file.

I've been trying to use Gulp to do this is VS2019 using gulp-sass.  I've followed many tutorials and have come up with the following gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./Main.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

In my Main.css I have the following:

```
$theme-colors: ( "primary": #fd7e14 );

@import "//lib/bootstrap-4.4.1/scss/bootstrap";

body {
    color: #5CFF54;
    background: rgb(92,18,18);
    height: 400vh;
}
```

However, the file that is being generated contains the following:

```
@import "//lib/bootstrap-4.4.1/scss/bootstrap";
body {
  color: #5CFF54;
  background: #5c1212;
  height: 400vh; }
```

I was expecting it to pull all of the individual styles into the produced CSS file, not just add the import.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you install bootstrap via npm: `npm i bootstrap`, then you can import it with `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`, thats with all npm packages, ~ points to the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trawling of the internet I have discovered that this is expected behaviour, and is down to the way I am referencing the source bootstrap.scss file.

In short, I am referencing it with web path, this has the effect of adding an import statement to the produced .css file.  If I change the reference to a filesystem path such as this:

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap-4.4.1/scss/bootstrap";
```

it functions as I had hoped and the produced .css file includes all of the definitions from bootstrap.scss.